# Error on WCF file

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a simple WCF application. In the file IService.cs:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IService
   {
       [OperationContract]
       List<ActiveSP> GetActiveSP();
   }

  [DataContract]
  public class ActiveSP
  {
     [DataMember]
     public string DESCR { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In the file Service.svc.cs:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
   public class Service : IService
   {
      SqlConnection Conn;
      SqlCommand Cmd;
      public Service()
      {
         Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=myweb;Initial Catalog=PeopleSoft;Integrated Security=True;");
      }

     public List<ActiveSP> GetActiveSP()
     {
        Conn.Open();
        Cmd = new SqlCommand();
        Cmd.Connection = Conn;
        Cmd.CommandText = "Select DESCR from myTable"; // return column (varchar type) 
        SqlDataReader Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<ActiveSP> 1stSP = new List<ActiveSP>(); // wrong here
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            // blah
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

The error please see the image:
[image: error]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a variable **1stSP**, the first character in a variable name needs to be a letter or an underscore, not a number.

[Here is some more information on valid identifiers](http://blog.visualt4.com/2009/02/creating-valid-c-identifiers.html)

Comment: sorry, I should be carefull between "l" and "1".

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a variable name with a number. That's what's throwing it off.

Answer (score 0):

rename 1spSP to firstSP or something like that :)
Identifiers can't start with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a variable name with a digit in C# I'm pretty sure.